# Order $\epsilon^2$ mean rate of change in action variable for adiabatic oscillator

Tags: classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, harmonic-oscillator, hamiltonian-formalism, adiabatic

In adiabatic theory of classical mechanics, considering a linear oscillator with a slowly changing frequency $\omega=\omega(t)$, [Percival and Richards](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521281490)'s nice book (pp. 144-147) discusses how it is useful to use angle-action variables $(\theta,I)$ to show that the action $I$ remain approximately unchanged during the system's period.

The time variable $t$ is scaled to $\lambda=\epsilon t$, where $\epsilon$ is small, for convenience and $\omega(\lambda)$ only changes significantly in a scaled time of order $\lambda=1$. We have now $\frac{d\omega}{dt}=\epsilon \frac{d\omega}{d\lambda}=\epsilon \omega'$. The adiabatic nature is given by
$$ \text{period}\times |\frac{d\omega}{dt}|=|\epsilon \omega'(\lambda)|\ll\omega^{2} $$
whereas the linear oscillator Hamiltonian is given by
$$ H=p^{2}/2m+\frac{1}{2}m\omega(\lambda)^{2}q^{2} .$$

When unperturbed and $\omega$ is constant in time, we know that the system can be represented by action variables $(\theta,I)$ such as
$$ q=\sqrt{\frac{2I}{m\omega(\lambda)}}\sin\theta, \ \ \ p=\sqrt{2mI\omega(\lambda)}\cos\theta, \ \ \ \ H(I)=\omega I$$
with the generating funtion
$$ S_{1}(\theta,q;\lambda)=\frac{1}{2}m\omega(\lambda)q^{2}\cot\theta. $$

This basic angle-action description can now be used as a perturbative approximation when $\omega$ changes slowly with time. The new Hamilotnian $K$ will be
$$ K(\theta,I,\lambda)=\omega(\lambda)I+\partial S_{1}/\partial t= \omega(\lambda)I+\epsilon I \frac{\omega'(\lambda)}{2\omega(\lambda)}\sin2\theta $$
and the equations of motion become:
$$ \frac{d\theta}{dt}=\omega(\lambda)+\epsilon \frac{\omega'(\lambda)}{2\omega(\lambda)}\sin2\theta $$
$$ \frac{dI}{dt}=-\epsilon I \frac{\omega'(\lambda)}{\omega(\lambda)}\cos2\theta $$

It is clear from the equation for $\frac{d\theta}{dt}$ and the fact that $|\epsilon\omega'/\omega^2|\ll 1$ that we can deduce the approximately linear dependence of angle on time, with $\theta$ increasing by $\pi$ in a time interval of approximately $\pi/\omega$.

**Question:**

The text then mentions that the equation for $\frac{dI}{dt}$ can be similarly used to deduce that when $\theta$ changes by $\pi$, the action $I$ undergoes a change of order $\epsilon^{2}$, even though it oscillates with an amplitude of order $\epsilon$ during that interval. Specifically, it mentions that a change by $\pi$ in $\theta$ implies a change by $\epsilon^2$ in the term:
$$\frac{\omega'}{2\omega}\sin2\theta.$$

I am not very clear on how exactly the square dependence ($\epsilon^{2}$) was inferred here. Is it just a matter of considering $\omega'/\omega$ equivalent to another $\epsilon$?  If so, it is a bit confusing in light of the earlier statement that we took: $|\epsilon\frac{\omega'}{\omega}|\ll \omega$.

Any help explaining this is appreciated.